# Angular4 routing Error as component is not a part of any module

Tags: angular2-routing

i download a project from cli and taken 2 components 1)routing 2)Employeecompoent
**Routing.ts**

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core/src/metadata/ng_module';
import { EmployeeCompoennt } from './Employee/Employee.Compoennt'
import{AppComponent} from './app.component'

export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: AppComponent },
    { path: 'calc', component: EmployeeCompoennt }
];

export const ROUTING: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes);
```

**Employee.ts**

```
@Component({

})
export class EmployeeCompoennt{
```

**app.module.ts**

```
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import{ROUTING} from './Routing.component';
    import{EmployeeCompoennt} from '../app/Employee/Employee.Compoennt';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,ROUTING
      ],
      providers: [EmployeeCompoennt],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Here im getting Error as Employee component is not a part of any module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the  "EmployeeComponent" should be declared in declarations array not in the providers (cause providers is for services ) .

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare EmployeeCompoennt in the declaration and also EmployeeCompoennt class name should be EmployeeComponent.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    EmployeeCompoennt
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,ROUTING
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```